# How to solve javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''

Tags: java, email, jsp, jakarta-mail

I wrote this `index.jsp` code for sends a mail for another person using Gmail. But it's not working and give this error to me.

> "type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> description
>
> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
> ```
>
> root cause
>
> ```
> javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
> ```
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the `GlassFish` Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2 logs. 
>   ".

```
    <%-- 
         Document   : index
         Created on : Mar 26, 2019, 7:48:36 PM
          Author     : ADITHYA
    --%>

    <%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>
    <%@page import="javax.mail.*"%>
    <%@page import="javax.mail.internet.*"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sending an email</title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="displayResult()">
        <h1>Sending an email</h1>

        <%!
            public static class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator{

            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication (){
            return new PasswordAuthentication("portaluniverses","xxxxx");
    }
    }

            %>
            <%
              int result=0;
              if(request.getParameter("send")!=null){

                  String d_uname="portaluniverses@gmail.com";
                  String d_password="xxxxx";
                  String d_host ="smtp.gmail.com";
                  int d_port=465;

                  String m_to=new String();
                  String m_from = "portaluniverses@gmail.com";
                  String m_subject=new String();
                  String m_text=new String();

                  if(request.getParameter("to")!=null){
                      m_to = request.getParameter("to");
                  }
                   if(request.getParameter("subject")!=null){
                      m_subject = request.getParameter("subject");
                  }
                   if(request.getParameter("message")!=null){
                    m_text="<h1>welcome to  sasts </h1>";
                    m_text =m_text.concat(request.getParameter("message"));
                    m_text = m_text.concat("<br/><h2>hope you got link</h2>");
                   }

                   //creat property object
                   Properties props = new Properties();

                   //creat SMTPAuthentication object
                   SMTPAuthenticator auth =new SMTPAuthenticator(); 

                   //creat a mail sesion object 
                   Session ses = Session.getInstance(props,auth);
                   //creat a MIME style email message  object
                   MimeMessage msg =new MimeMessage(ses);
                   msg.setContent(m_text, "text/html");
                   msg.setSubject(m_subject);
                   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(m_from));
                   msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));


                   try{
                       Transport transport= ses.getTransport("SMTPS");

                       transport.connect(d_host,d_port, d_uname,d_password);

                       transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

                       transport.close();   

                       result=1;

                   }catch(Exception e){
                       out.println(e);
                   }
              }

            %>       


        <form name="myForm" action="index.jsp" method="POST">
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <tr>To:</tr>
                       <tr> <input type="text" name="To" value="" /></tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subject</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="subject" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Message</td>
                        <td><textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>  </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%= result %>" />
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
        </form>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                function displayResult(){
                    if(document.myForm.hidden.value === "1"){
                        alert("Mail was sent");
                    }
                }

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to show password publically

Comment: Did you check what is printing `m_to`? `System.out.println(m_to )`

Comment: If m_to can contain multiple addresses, use the InternetAddress.parse method.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code,

```
final String username = "portaluniverses@gmail.com";
final String password = "xxxxx";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Then create a session

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
  });
```

And then send your email,

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(messageText);
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Try it why? What part of this constitutes the solution, and why, to what problem?

Comment: @user207421 He needs to improve his code. He didn't declare the `properties` correctly. And he might need to set `mail.smtps.auth` and `mail.smtps.starttls.enable` to `true` for Gmail.

Comment: He didn't declare the `Properties` correctly *how*? And where does the value of `to` magically come from? Which is the only point at issue?

Comment: `to` Send the email to which address?